# Update DLL without having to recompile applications using it

Tags: c#, dynamic, dll, console, .net-assembly

I have a single C# solution with 3 projects in it:

1) A Console Application implementing a TCP Server

2) A Console Application implementing a TCP Client

3) A DLL file that both the server and the client use

My aim would be to not having to recompile the whole solution just when the DLL changes. After adding the DLL to references to both projects, the Copy Local value is True. With this, all projects have to be recompiled when the DLL changes, but at least it works.

If I set it to False, I get the following issue:
c:\Users\Attila\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TcpCommunicator\TcpServer\bin\Debug>TcpServer.exe

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'TcpCommonElements, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=98782ff4b5018a35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   TcpServer.Server.Main(String[] args)

I have added the following snippet in the App.config file for both the Server and Client, but does not seem to have an impact:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="TcpCommonElements"
                          publicKeyToken="98782ff4b5018a35"
                          culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I tried having the assembly not Strong Named, to no avail. The dll is present in the directory where it is referenced in the projects.

What am I overlooking? Or is my understanding of dynamic libraries flawed?

edit: Just to clarify, the public interfaces do not change. Let's say the modification is switching from

```
System.Console.WriteLine("---");
```

to

```
System.Console.WriteLine("+++");
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that

Comment: @zombie then what is the point of dynamic libraries? Also I edited the question, clarifying that the public interfaces do not change, only the underlying implementation.

Comment: Strong naming is a bit complicated. Your library now may be in GAC, and since you never changed the version, the old version is still a valid DLL for your reference. If you want to use strong named assemblies, learn a bit about how they work - it's not simple, and you'll need proper versioning. When you remove the strong naming, does the error stay the same, with the same public key token? If so, that means the reference didn't actually change. I'd stick to normal project references if I were you; this isn't C++, the public interface isn't in a header file - it's part of the assembly.

Comment: And just for completion, with strong naming and proper versioning, the right way to handle flexible dependencies is via assembly binding redirects - the redirection isn't automatic since .NET can't know if the versions are actually compatible. If you really think you can keep your versions proper, you can easily set it to use the latest version of a dependent library. I'd still recommend avoiding that, unless you *really* know what you're doing, though; it's a very easy way to introduce many hard to find issues.

Comment: @Luaan thank you for response. If I remove strong naming, the error is different only in the public key, as now it says "null". 

So far mostly i worked in C++ and that is why I thought it might be done as simply, so your hunch was correct as in "this isn't C++".

But it is still not fully clear to me then what is the point of "Local Copy" in case they are in the same solution. But now I understand from your answer that in C# it is not like how I expected it to be.

Comment: Well, of course you need to have local copy enabled - that makes sure the DLL is actually there for the executables to find :) If you want to share the DLLs in a different way, you still can - by using a post-build event, for example, or by changing the output directory of all the projects to one shared directory. Same solution doesn't mean one output directory - by default, each project has its own output directory (bin/Debug etc.). There's a lot of differences between VC# and VC++; but C# is designed to "work by default" - you only really need to change defaults when it has a purpose.

Comment: "Copy local" just means "copy this reference to my build output directory", which is usually exactly what you want for project references. The referenced project is built when it's out of date, and if you change anything in the project, it's out of date - that's how the build system works (to try and help you avoid silly versioning mistakes, which almost inevitably arise when you try to work around this :)). It's a typical case of "don't optimise too soon" - C# compilation is absurdly faster than C++'s; you might be surprised how unnecessary build optimisations are even for 10M+ LoC projects.

Comment: Try binding redirects https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx.